# How to pass an %md parameter from a dynamic form of Apache Zeppelin to %pyspark?

Tags: apache-zeppelin, dynamicform

My Zeppelin 0.10.0 configuration (on a server) has only livy, markdown and angular interpreters. Thus, ZeppelinContext is not accessible (I suppose).
I define

```
%md
${name=sun}
```

in one paragraph.
How can I access the  value of "name" in the subsequent paragraph with %pyspark (or %spark)?

Comment: I found an answer. 
You have to declare the variable to be 'for the whole notebook' by
%md
$${variable=}
and later use it livy.sql   in create table temp as select  $${varable=} as variable
It can be passd to %pyspark and %pysark by using SparkContext then.